# How to count the number of occurrence of a word in a column

Tags: python, dictionary, count, graphlab

I have a column named **word_count** which contains the count of all the words in a review. How can I find the  number of times the word **awesome** has occurred in each row of that column and use **.apply()** method to make it into a new column say **awesome**.

```
products['word_count'][1]
   {'and': 3L,'bags': 1L,'came': 1L, 'disappointed.':1L,'does':1L,'early':1L,'highly': 1L,'holder.': 1L, 'awesome': 2L}
```

how can i get the output

```
products['awesome'][1]
   2
```

[image: The awesome column must be created and it must contain the number of occurrence of awesome taken form word_count column]

Comment: Could it be your answer: `str(products['awesome'])[0]`

Comment: i don't think how that could be answer as i am looking to create the column 'awesome' which contains the number of occurrence of the word awesome taken form the 'word_count' column.

Comment: Please draw a proper matrix and share with us for explaining your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from you is that you have a dictionary called products which holds word counter for various texts like this:

```
products = {'word_count' : [{'holder.': 2, 'awesome': 1}, {'and': 3,'bags': 1,'came': 1, 'disappointed.':1,'does':1,'early':1,'highly': 1,'holder.': 1, 'awesome': 2}] }
```

for instance, the first text contains "holder" 2 times and awesome 1 time.
To add another column you need to create the array that counts 'awesome' on each text as follows:

```
counter = []
for i in range(len(products['word_count'])):
    counter.append(products['word_count'][i]['awesome'])
```

and then add the row to the table:

```
products['awesome'] = counter
```

and there you have it!

Comment: IndexError: Invalid type to use for indexing. I am getting this error

Comment: Could you write what exactly is `products`? It's hard to know his type.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for the python function counting_words:

```
def counting_words(x):
    if (products['word_count'][x].has_key('awesome')):
        return products['word_count'][x]['awesome']
    else:
        return 0
```

Here's the other part of the code

```
new_dict = {}
for x in range(len(products)):
    if (x==0):
        new_dict['awesome'] = [counting_words(x)]
    new_dict['awesome'].append(counting_words(x))

newframe = graphlab.SFrame(new_dict)
products.add_columns(newframe)
```

I assumed that you are using graphlab and the above code will work for the word 'awesome'. The new_dict was created to store the count of 'awesome' in each row of your product['word_count'] column. So in new_dict it should be: new_dict = {'awesome': [0,0,1,...2,1]}.
However, if you plan to count other words, this method would be too slow.